# How do I invoke token substitution with Pet?

Tags: emails

I have to send some emails in a custom Drupal 7 module.

I'd like to use the PET module (*Previewable email templates*) to manage the templates and `drupal_mail()` to send emails because it already uses SwiftMailer to send emails.
The problem is that the body of the email I get from Pet has some tokens that I should replace before the email is sent.

How can I replace them?

This is the code I'm using.

```
$pet = pet_load('test1');

$params['format']= "text/html";
$params['charset']= "UTF-8";
$params['email_subject']= $pet->subject;
$params['email_body']=$pet->mail_body;

///$params['email_body']= <body with token replaced>

drupal_mail('myLib', 'customNotifications', 'xxx@gmail.com', language_default(), $params);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved in this way:

```
// SOSTITUZIONE TOKEN DRUPAL
$l_oPetTemplate = pet_load('test1');
$l_TemParams2['pet'] = $l_oPetTemplate;
$l_aSubstitutions = pet_substitutions($l_oPetTemplate, $l_TemParams2);
$l_aEmailParams['email_subject'] = token_replace($l_oPetTemplate->subject, $l_aSubstitutions, array('clear' => TRUE));
$l_aEmailParams['email_body']=token_replace($l_oPetTemplate->mail_body, $l_aSubstitutions, array('clear' => TRUE));
```